# What is the minimum version of macos Apple support?

Tags: ios, macos, osx-yosemite

I'm using mac OS X Yosemite version 10.10.5.
I wonder if Apple still supports or has already stopped support for this old version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple supports usually the current and at most the two lastest versions.

After the release of macOS 11 Big Sur macOS 10.13 High Sierra became EOL (end of life). macOS 10.10 Yosemite RIP (rests in peace) for a long time.